# SwitfUI: Why can't the wrapped value of a @State variable be reassigned during initialisation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, initialization

Why can't the wrapped value of a @State variable be reassigned during initialisation.

In the code below, I am initialising a @State variable, however reassigning its wrapped value doesn't work. An entirely new wrapper object needs to be created.

Why doesn't SwiftUI allow reassignment here?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
     init() {
        _str = State(initialValue: "value")
        
        /* Reassignemnt doesn't work. */
        str = "newValue"
        
        /* Ok */
        _str = State(initialValue: "newValue")
    }
    
    @State private var str: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(str)
    }
}
```

Comment: ["Why" isn't a good question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) You can't reassign it because that is just how `@State` was designed. Do you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: No, I don't have an XY problem.

Comment: Okay, then you need to [edit] your question to make it very clear what kind of answers you are looking for.

Comment: Likely Because SwiftUI property wrappers in general are not available during init

Answer (score 1):

Because the backing storage object that holds the dynamic view model data (according to its identity in the `View` hierarchy) isn't created until the screen content defined by this `View` struct is about to appear on screen. And that happens right before `body` is called. Don't implement `init` and stick with `@State private var str: String = "default"` and you won't run into any issues.

Define the `@State` in a parent `View` struct and pass it down to child `Views` as a `let` for readonly access (transform into a child View init via computed property) or the dollar syntax into a `@Binding var` for read/write (which by the way is convenience for get/set closures). `body` is called whenever a var is set if it was previously read, i.e. it's like an `onChange` for all the `View`'s `let`s/`var`s.